# Problems back button and resubmitting the form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

I am having problems when the back button is used and a form is resubmitted, the value on the model that is bound to the drop down list is not retained on the second submission.

In real life, this code is a report generator - the form collects parameters from the user and then posts it to a results view where the data is displayed. Obviously this is a fairly complex bit of code to post, but below I have some simple code exhibiting the same bug:

I have a model like so:

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public string SomeText { get; set; }

    public long SelectedItemId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableItems { get; set; }

}
```

A form that submits an instance of the model like so:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Result", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeText)
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItemId, Model.AvailableItems)
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

And a view that shows the details, like so

```
You Typed: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SomeText) <br />

You Selected: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SelectedItemId)
```

And a controller to manage it all:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            HomeModel model = new HomeModel();

            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() });

            model.AvailableItems = items;


            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult Result(HomeModel model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

I fill in the form, press submit. I am redirected to the Results view and all is well.

Then I press back in the browser, and I am shown the Index view again.

Then I submit the form again and things turn sour. The model is not being repopulated with the selected value from my list, despite the list appearing to show the previously selected value in the browser.

The string property is being updated correctly, and this is true in the real world code that I have displaying this behaviour.

This only happens in IE, I am using version 9.

Comment: How did you set up the html form, can you share the code with form on it

Comment: I've added the top parts of the form the to op, I've omitted most of it as it is quite complex further down the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution.

Short answer: don't suffix your model properties with 'Id'

When I first load the index view in the example, this is what gets rendered:

```
<SELECT id=SelectedItemId name=SelectedItemId data-val-required="The field is required"...>
```

When I submit, press back and then check the source, this is what I get:

```
<select name="SelectedItem" id="SelectedItem">
```

Notice that the name of the element has been changed, severely disrupting MVC's deserializers.

This can be seen in the URLs that are being posted, when I first post the form, this is the url that is shown in the browser:

```
http://localhost:57175/Home/Result?SomeText=999&SelectedItemId=1
```

Then, when I press back and post again, this is what is shown:

```
http://localhost:57175/Home/Result?SomeText=999&SelectedItem=1
```

I can live with changing the property name, but the trouble is that it also strips all of the validation attributes that are needed for using unobtrusive validation. Can anyone enlighten me on how to retain those?

Comment: Clear IE's temporary files (Ctrl+Shift+Del). I've seen IE do weird things with the cache and the back button while developing MVC applications, sometimes it shows a view as it was weeks ago, even though the view has been displayed properly hundreds of times after that.

Comment: It seems to be caused by the form redirecting the browser, if the example is altered so that the form redisplays the index page, the problem goes away

Comment: @CodeCaster I have also seen this with IE, an annoying bug for sure but this in this case it does not seem to solve the problem

Comment: In that case you need to clarify the URL's you see per step (form - post - get) as it's hard to keep track of your story. :-) In `Results()` you don't seem to fill `model.AvailableItems`, so if that is displayed, the select will be empty.

Comment: @CodeCaster, thats right I don't fill the available items, but I don't need to display it in results, just the value that was selected. I will add the URLs just now

Answer (score 1):

Right, this is definitely all working correctly now.

It was related to where I was inserting the script tags for the validation. I was being lazy and just stuck them in at the top of the views, so when the entire page was assembled and rendered they were in the body.

IE seemed to take exception to this and when the back button was pressed, the script references disappeared, as did all of the validation attributes and the 'Id' off the name of my property. Kind of odd but there you go

So, the moral of the story is to always put the scripts in the correct place.